# Is it possible to play audio to my bluetooth on iphone?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headphones, headset

I would like to listen to my podcasts through my bluetooth headset and then be able to answer calls when they come in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, the iPhone can now stream music over Bluetooth as long as:

- Your iPhone has OS 3.0 or newer installed
- Your iPhone is 3G or newer
- Your Bluetooth headset supports the Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP), often referred to as Stereo Bluetooth

More info in this Apple Tech Support article:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1664